# Adding uploaded by (user name or name) Automatically while uploading the Excel into SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to upload Excel data into SQL Server with uploaded by (i.e which pick from session method)

I have created table name, country, address, uploaded by.

Normally the upload is working fine but I want to add the uploaded by value while uploading the excel bulk upload

I don't know how to insert the uploaded by value in bulk upload some one help me

This is my code:

```
try
{
    myExcelConn.Open();

    // GET DATA FROM EXCEL SHEET.
    OleDbCommand objOleDB = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", myExcelConn);

    // READ THE DATA EXTRACTED FROM THE EXCEL FILE.
    OleDbDataReader objBulkReader = null;

    objBulkReader = objOleDB.ExecuteReader();

    // SET THE CONNECTION STRING.
    string sCon = sqlconn;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sCon))
    {
        con.Open();
        //SqlConnection p = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\jetback\source\repos\Projectstudent\webdown_up_load\App_Data\upload.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        // FINALLY, LOAD DATA INTO THE DATABASE TABLE.
        oSqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
        oSqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Table3"; // TABLE NAME.

        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "name");
        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("address", "address");
        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("country", "country");
        oSqlBulk.WriteToServer(objBulkReader);
    }

    lblConfirm.Text = "DATA IMPORTED SUCCESSFULLY.";
    lblConfirm.Attributes.Add("style", "color:green");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblConfirm.Text = ex.Message;
    lblConfirm.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");
}
finally
{
    // CLEAR.
    oSqlBulk.Close();
    oSqlBulk = null;
    myExcelConn.Close();
    myExcelConn = null;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Can u elaborate more?

Comment: this is the best one to help you: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/import-excel-data-into-sql-table-using-sqlbulkcopy-in-c-sharp/

Comment: Yes. This the query for uploading the excel data in sql server. And i have created table name,address,county,added by. In excel i have a column name,address,country. In this added by value i want to add this extra while bulk upload. For example in excel value(john, 121 kl street, Delhi).but while uploading it should add the value uploadby(john,121 kl street,Delhi,aravindhan)

Comment: @DanielB Bro i know to upload the data but i want to add the added by that is login user name                                                                                                   oSqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Table3"; // TABLE NAME.
**Here i want to add the column  added by. While uploading it should added the added by user name automatically in column **
        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "name");
        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("address", "address");
        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("country", "country");
        oSqlBulk.WriteToServer(objBulkReader);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use DataTable if you want to add more col when there's already data in yr dataSet:

```
var results = new DataTable();
using(var myExcelConn = new OleDbConnection(excCnnStr))
{
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", myExcelConn))
    {
        myExcelConn.Open();

        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(results);
    }
}

//add new col
results.Columns.Add("uploadedBy", typeof(System.Int32));
foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
{
    row["uploadedBy"] = loggedInUserId; // set uploader
}

using (var con = new SqlConnection(sCon))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var oSqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
    {
        oSqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Table3";

        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "name");
        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("address", "address");
        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("country", "country");
        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("uploadedBy", "uploadedBy");
        oSqlBulk.WriteToServer(results);
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach (var row in results.Rows)
{
    **row["uploadedBy"]** = loggedInUserId; // set uploader
} here its throwing an error like cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type 'object' dynamic

Comment: change foreach (var row in results.Rows) to foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)  :)

Comment: Working fine bro and i have another doubt how to remove the duplicate while uploading excel file. Can i use delete comment to compare with row by row  while uploading

Comment: @AravindhanR u can remove duplicates by  results.DefaultView.ToTable( true); // distinct the rows

Comment: u can also be more specific results.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "name", "country");

Comment: Did you try? @AravindhanR

Comment: No bro i didn't try. Today i will try @Daniel

Comment: Bro another doubt shall i use select distinct(*) from sheet1 to remove the duplicate from excel sheet?@Daniel

Comment: Bro this is working fine. Many thanks bro. And can you send mail id bro bcz if i have any doubt i can able to ask directly through mail. This is my mail id aravindhan32@outlook.com.

Comment: @AravindhanR sure

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get from Excel and then insert into SQL.

```
//After objBulkReader = objOleDB.ExecuteReader();
 if (objBulkReader.HasRows)
        {

            while (objBulkReader.Read())
            {       string newname = objBulkReader[0].ToString();
                    string address= objBulkReader[1].ToString();
                    string country= objBulkReader[2].ToString();
                    string uploadedby=Session["uploader"].ToString();
                 //insert these into SQL db by SQL connection

             }
      }
```

The 0,1 and 2 in objBulkReader are column positions in Excel.